# Cant switch type Radio Box in vue-3

Tags: javascript, radio-button, vuejs3

I created type='radio' in 'ListSwitcher' component in Vue 3, radio have 2 option- 'listChecked' and 'mapChecked', checking the value 'mapChecked' with mounted, it shows correctly. But i cant to switch on 'listChecked' manually on the page. What i do wrong.

```
<div class="switcher">
    <input
      id="list"
      :checked="checked.listChecked"
      type="radio"
      class="changeState changeStateList"
      @change="listChange; checked.listChecked = true;"
    />
    <label for="list" class="listBtn"> </label>

    <input
      id="map"
      :checked="checked.mapChecked"
      type="radio"
      class="changeState changeStateMap"
      @change="mapChange; checked.mapChecked = true"
    />
    <label for="map" class="mapBtn"> </label>
    <span class="roundToggle"></span>
  </div>
```

and script

```
props: {
    state: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  emits: ['listSwitch'],
  data() {
    return {
      checked: {
        listChecked: null,
        mapChecked: null,
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.state === 'map') {
      this.checked.mapChecked = true;
    }
    console.log(this.checked.mapChecked)
  },
  methods: {
    listChange() {
      {
        this.$emit('listSwitch', 'list');
      }
    },
    mapChange() {
      {
        this.$emit('listSwitch', 'map');
      }
    },
    emits: ['listSwitch'],
  },
```

I have a separate component that I import radio into, and with importing this component have a code

`<div class="state-change">     <ListSwitcher @listSwitch="onClickListSwitcher"                   state="map"/>   </div>`

Comment: Now I found out that the main problem is that when you select another button, the first one remains active, how to make it so that when you select another button, the first one is deactivated

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<template>
    <div class="switcher">
        <input id="list" :checked="checked.listChecked" type="radio" class="changeState changeStateList"
            @change="listChange" />
        <label for="list" class="listBtn"> </label>

        <input id="map" :checked="checked.mapChecked" type="radio" class="changeState changeStateMap"
            @change="mapChange" />
        <label for="map" class="mapBtn"> </label>
        <span class="roundToggle"></span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        state: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            checked: {
                listChecked: false,
                mapChecked: false,
            },
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        if (this.state === 'map') {
            this.checked.mapChecked = true;
        } else if (this.state === 'list') {
            this.checked.listChecked = true;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        listChange() {
            this.checked.listChecked = true;
            this.checked.mapChecked = false;
            this.$emit('listSwitch', 'list');
        },
        mapChange() {
            this.checked.listChecked = false;
            this.checked.mapChecked = true;
            this.$emit('listSwitch', 'map');
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: YES!!! it works correctly, great thanks to u!